# How do I join a Facebook group with my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups

Recently Facebook showed me a message in one of the Facebook groups I'm admin of which said "Now pages can join groups" or something like that, and there was one page among regular Facebook people accounts waiting for approval to join my group. Now I want to join some groups with some of my Facebook pages, but I dont see instructions anywhere how to do it, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature needs to be rolled out to the group you would like to join as well as the page you would like to join.
(I don't believe it's 100% rolled out to everyone)

In addition, the admin must enable it in the group settings.

`https://www.facebook.com/groups/<group_name>/edit/`

[image: Group page join settings]

Once, that's done, you should be given the option.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be available to some groups